# React Native WebView Not working

Tags: react-native, webview

I have one chess board embed on my hand. I want to be able to cover the wide and height of this embed code device. I could have worked like the picture below. Buttons are small. If there are those who have knowledge in this matter, I will be happy if they help. I looked, but I did not get a result. Respects.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyC3U.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdPcs.png)

```
 <View style={{ flex:1 }}>

        <WebView

                scrollEnabled={false}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                style={ styles.WebViewContainer }          
                source={{uri: 'https://chessmicrobase.com/microbases/10/games/208?token=kpj3f9ez&embedded=1#hp-'}}
        />


    </View>

 WebViewContainer: {
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center'
```

}

Comment: why there is a height in web view's parent style ?

Comment: @coyote Yes, only flex: 1 did. So how can we cover it. ? You must have noticed the difference in the pictures.

Comment: Problem solved. Webview  add properties scalesPageToFit={false}. Thank.

Comment: Add your answer and mark it as correct.